# How to include fields of related object in Mail Merge template?

Tags: custom-field, lookup, mail-merge

I am creating a mail merge template on opportunity. On Opportunity, we have a custom Account lookup field named `Supplier Name` (API name is `SupplierName__c`). I want to include this Account fields like Phone, Address etc in the mail merge template but I am not able to do this.

I can display Supplier Name but cannot retrieve other fields. To display phone, I tried this:

<< SupplierName_Phone >>

<< Supplier_Name_Phone>>

<< Opportunity_SupplierName_Phone>>

<< Opportunity_Supplier_Phone>>

Any Idea how it should be done?

Edit:
To display Supplier Name I using this formula `Opportunity_SupplierName` and it works.

Comment: Did you try using dot notation? SupplierName__r.Phone?

Comment: No. but as for as I know, dot notation is not allowed in mail merge templates. To display Supplier Name I used this formula `Opportunity_SupplierName` and it works.